# OpenTK - fragment shader is not working (triangle is always black)

Tags: c#, opengl, fragment-shader, opentk

I'm trying to draw a triangle using an OpenGL(OpenTK) fragment shader.

But always displayed black triangle. (even I changed color in fragment shader.)

Maybe fragment shader is not working.

How to fix it?

I attached my code.

P.S. I'm sorry if I do something wrong with this Post. This is my first time on this site.

### Render

```cs
window.RenderFrame += (FrameEventArgs args) =>
            {
                GL.UseProgram(shaderProgram.shaderProgramId);

                GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);


                float[] verts = { -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f };


                int vao = GL.GenVertexArray();
                int vertices = GL.GenBuffer();

                GL.BindVertexArray(vao);
                GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, vertices);
                GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, verts.Length * sizeof(float), verts, BufferUsageHint.StaticCopy);
                GL.VertexAttribPointer(0, 3, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false,3 * sizeof(float),0);
                GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(0);

                GL.DrawArrays(OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL4.PrimitiveType.Triangles, 0, 3);

                GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, 0);
                GL.BindVertexArray(0);
                GL.DeleteVertexArray(vao);
                GL.DeleteBuffer(vertices);


                window.SwapBuffers();
            };
```

### Shader Load

```cs
public static Shader LoadShader(string shaderLocation, ShaderType shaderType)
        {
            int shaderId = GL.CreateShader(shaderType);
            GL.ShaderSource( shaderId, File.ReadAllText( shaderLocation ) );
            GL.CompileShader( shaderId );
            string infoLog = GL.GetShaderInfoLog(shaderId);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(infoLog))
            {
                throw new Exception(infoLog);
            }

            return new Shader() {shaderId = shaderId};
        }
```

### Program binding

```cs
public static ShaderProgram LoadShaderProgram(string vertexShaderLocation, string fragmentShaderLocation)
        {
            int shaderProgramId = GL.CreateProgram();

            Shader vertexShader = LoadShader(vertexShaderLocation, ShaderType.VertexShader);
            Shader fragShader = LoadShader(fragmentShaderLocation, ShaderType.FragmentShader);

            GL.AttachShader(shaderProgramId, vertexShader.shaderId);
            GL.AttachShader(shaderProgramId, fragShader.shaderId);
            GL.LinkProgram(shaderProgramId);
            GL.DetachShader(shaderProgramId, vertexShader.shaderId);
            GL.DetachShader(shaderProgramId, fragShader.shaderId);
            GL.DeleteShader(vertexShader.shaderId);
            GL.DeleteShader(fragShader.shaderId);

            string infoLog = GL.GetProgramInfoLog(shaderProgramId);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(infoLog))
            {
                throw new Exception(infoLog);
            }

            return new ShaderProgram() {shaderProgramId = shaderProgramId};
        }
```

### shaders

#### vertex

```c
#version 330

layout(location=0) in vec3 vPosition;

out vec4 vertexColor;

void main() {
    gl_Position = vec4( vPosition, 1.0);
    vertexColor = vec4(0.0,1.0,0.0,1.0);
}
```

#### fragment

```c
#version 330

out vec4 FragColor;

in vec4 vertexColor;

void main()
{
    FragColor = vertexColor;
}
```

Comment: I was cleared by using ClearColor(Color.Red) in Load

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of problems with your code. The main reason you may not see your shader in action is because you do not keep your shaders attached to your shader handle (shaderProgramId). Instead, you detach and delete them right after you compiled and attached them. What you are doing there is basically creating your shader program and then immediately throwing it away.

Another issue (which might not cause your main problem, but yet) may be your usage of a VAO. A VAO is actually meant to preserve the OpenGL states of the objects bound to it across state switches. It is rather a container for VBOs inside it, holding their descriptions. So what you want to do is to create your VAO, bind it, then create, bind and describe (glVertexAttribPointer) your VBOs. After that you can unbind your VAO. When you bind it again, you don't have to do anything extra (like binding VBOs or using glVertexAttribPointer again): What you did when first binding your VAO and adding your VBOs is stored in the VAO. Just bind the VAO, bind your shader (glUseProgram) and happily render away.

Comment: After attaching shaders to a program and linking it they can [safely be detached and deleted](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/47910/after-a-succesful-gllinkprogram-should-i-delete-detach-my-shaders).